# Pycharm : Cant run unit tests with command line arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pycharm, command-line-arguments

here is my test class

```
class TestProjectCreation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        self.project = ClassA('adasdasd', self.project_path)

    def test_etl_project(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.project.project_name,'adasdasd')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and here is `ClassA`

```
class ClassA(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self, project_name, project_path):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(project_name, project_path)
```

and finally, here is `BaseClass`

```
class BaseClass(object):

    def __init__(self, project_name, project_path):
        self.project_path = project_path
        self.project_name = project_name
        self.parser = self.create_option_parser()
        (self.options, args) = self.parser.parse_args()
        self.check_mandatory_options(self.options)
        self.check_project_name(self.options)

    def check_mandatory_options(self, options):
        missing_arguments = []

        if not options.para1:
            missing_arguments.append('para1')
        if not options.para2:
            missing_arguments.append('para2')
        if len(missing_arguments) > 0:
            raise ValueError('Required argument(s) missing: {}'.format(missing_arguments))
```

note

```
self.parser = self.create_option_parser()
(self.options, args) = self.parser.parse_args()
```

hence the `BaseClass` is expecting some command line arguments

and in my pycharm config

`Additional Arguments: --para1 val1 --para2 val2`

[image]

but when I run the test, I get

```
Testing started at 11:05 AM ...
/path/to/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 51688 --file "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path /path/to/project/tests/project_unit_tests.py -- --para1 val1 --para2 val2
pydev debugger: process 98200 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 181.5087.37)
Usage: python -m unittest discover [options]

python -m unittest discover: error: no such option: --para1
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest discover -s /path/to/project/test -p project_unit_tests.py -t /path/to/project/test --para1 val1 --para2 val2 in /path/to/project/test


Process finished with exit code 2
Empty test suite.
```

why am I getting this
`python -m unittest discover: error: no such option: --para1`
?

how can I pass command line arguments to my object via unit test? Note that when I run my `main_project.py`

```
def main():

    project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    project = ClassA('adasdasd', self.project_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

as

`python main_project.py --para1 val1 --para2 val2`

this runs just fine. I also tried

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("ERROR command-line parameter must be supplied for these tests")
    command_line_param = sys.argv[1]
    del sys.argv[1:]
    unittest.main()
```

as part of my `TestProjectCreation` but still got the same error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late in offering this answer, but maybe it will help others that come across this post.

You can think of each test case in your unit test as a preparation script for running your test target. Because most unit test frameworks should reset the system back to the same state at the start of each individual test case, you can set sys.argv to be in the state you wish to test against in the setup function (most unit test frameworks should run the setup function between each test case).

Having said that, I can't recall off the top of my head if there is an exception to this claim, so if this doesn't work a good place to start would be to confirm how unit testing framework you're using resets the testing environment between test cases.

With that in mind, it seems sensible to create the setup function to look something like this, for your case at least:

```
def setUp(self):
    import sys
    # first argument in argv is always the path and name of the script being
    # executed, in this case, it's your unit test script
    # followed by your various command args, in the order written into 
    # the terminal.
    sys.argv.extend(['--para1','val1','--para2','val2'])
    self.project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    self.project = ClassA('adasdasd', self.project_path)
```

For my own tests, this works fine. But I can't speak to how well this approach may, or may not generalize for more complex test situations.